# Can $X^TX$ have negative eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a real $X_{n\times p}$ matrix where $p > n$, can the matrix $X^T X$ have any negative eigenvalues? A derivation would be appreciated!

Comment: As a practical matter, numerical computations of the eigenvalues of $X^{T}X$ will often result in some small negative eigenvalues, even though in theory they're all non-negative.

Comment: Thanks for this important note. I indeed ran into this trouble and that is why I asked.

Comment: Is this a real matrix?

Comment: $-I=(iI)^T(iI)$.

Comment: Another good point. Yes, it is. Edited the question.

Comment: It's useful to know that $X^T X$ is positive semidefinite. Proof: $u^T X^T Xu = \| Xu \|^2 \geq 0$. We know that positive semidefinite matrices have nonnegative eigenvalues. So we see that the eigenvalues of $X^T X$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $X^\top X$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Note that $v \neq 0$, hence $\|v\|^2 \neq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
X^\top X v = \lambda v &\implies v^\top X^\top X v = \lambda v^\top v\\
&\implies (Xv)^\top (Xv) = \lambda v^\top v \\
&\implies \|Xv\|^2 = \lambda \|v\|^2 \\
&\implies \lambda = \frac{\|Xv\|^2}{\|v\|^2} \ge 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot.

You can show this by contradiction:
If $\lambda < 0$ was an eigenvalue with eigenvector $u$ $(\neq 0)$, you would have $$ \color{blue}{0 >} \lambda u^Tu =u^T(\lambda u) = u^TX^TXu = (Xu)^T(Xu) \color{blue}{\geq 0} \mbox{ Contradiction!}$$